# Packaging/Deploying Maven from Python

Tags: python, maven, subprocess

Big picture is I'm trying to automate my deployment process of building with maven and deploying to a web logic server. Little picture is I'm using subprocess to see if I can call maven from within python. When I attempt this subprocess mistakes mvn for a file.
Here is my code so far:

```
import subprocess


def main():
    print(subprocess.check_output(["mvn", "-v"]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And here's my error:

```
C:\pythondev\python.exe "C:/pythondev/development/deployment scripts/redploy-to-localhost.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/pythondev/development/deployment scripts/redploy-to-localhost.py", line 9, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/pythondev/development/deployment scripts/redploy-to-localhost.py", line 5, in main
    subprocess.check_output(["a"])
  File "C:\pythondev\lib\subprocess.py", line 376, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\pythondev\lib\subprocess.py", line 453, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\pythondev\lib\subprocess.py", line 756, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\pythondev\lib\subprocess.py", line 1155, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Although my issue is with subprocess I'm open to answers that suggest a better alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it worked for me.

```
print(subprocess.check_output(["mvn", "-v"], shell=True))
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and was hesistant to use `shell=True`, because the internet tells me this is evil.

When I run `where mvn` in my cmd.exe, I can see that there are two matches:

- `mvn`, which is a Unix shell-script (it starts with `#!/bin/sh`),
- `mvn.cmd`, which is a Windows batch file.

I think what happens when you execute `mvn something -something` in `cmd.exe` is the following: Windows tries finding an executable called `mvn`. It finds the `mvn` file, but realizes that this file is not executable. It then tries finding files like `mvn.com`, `mvn.exe`, ... (see the `%PATHEXT%` system variable). When it finds `mvn.cmd`, it executes that and everyone is happy.

As far as I understand it, the problem with `subprocess.check_output` (and `subprocess.run`, and so on) is that the path-"expansion" via `%PATHEXT%` is not being performed. So the solution is that you have to give the extension manually and run your command as

```
print(subprocess.check_output(["mvn.cmd", "-v"]))
```